# Android USB Driver on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, drivers, android

I am running Windows 8 x64 Professional.

I updated my android USB driver to include my device (Sony Tablet S) as was instructed by the internet. Sadly, installing the driver seems difficult on Windows 8.

Looking around the internet, it seems I have to turn off signed driver enforcement in order to install the driver. My problem is, this advice arises from the time of Windows 8 RC and Preview. Windows 8 has now been released a little while now. Is there an official/less "hacky" way to install the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/), which claims to be an *automated install universal adb driver* fitting every Android device. You can find a more detailed description at [Liliputing.Com](http://liliputing.com/2013/04/koushs-universal-adb-driver-for-windows-makes-connectinghacking-android-devices-easier.html), including screenshots. Quoting from that article: *It doesn’t require you to disable driver verification on Windows 8, like some other drivers.* So this should be the solution to your problem, I'd say :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool, it will auto detect your device specific drivers and solve all the issues:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/tool-adb-fastboot-installer-tool-windows-t3999445

Just connect your phone in usb debugging mode and then run the tool

P.S I am the creator of this tool